# DNS configuration adding New Host(A or AAAA) and New Alias(CNAME)

Tags: windows, dns, hostname, fqdn

My provider shared me a document link about how to configure Dns and the document stated that i must add **New Host(A or AAAA)** like this:

```
Hostname:ns1
FQDN:ns1.domain.com
IP: 192.168.1.2 <= for example
```

And **New Alias(CNAME)** Like this:

```
Hostname: www
FQDN: www.domain.com
FQDN for target host: domain.com
```

i did what it mentioned. but website never showed up although it was searchable through `ip` address and `ns1.domain.name`.moreover,i read other websites guidelines and they also stated what document did.
**After a lot of efforts**, i couldn't solve the problem that, why website doesn't resolve while i search `domian.com` or `www.domain.com` in chrome.
So i tried to change every thing and tried below settings and it **WORKED !**.now the website can be searched in both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`

Add **New Host(A or AAAA)**

```
Hostname:www
FQDN:www.domain.com
IP: 192.168.1.2 <= for example
```

Recently, i read [this website](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/website-troubleshooting/cannot-access-using-ip-address) which says

> DNS Propagation- DNS changes to a domain may require 4-24 hours of
>   domain propagation before the change is recognized on the internet. If
>   you have made a change which affects an IP assignment (e.g. A record),
>   then you will need to allow for the propagation time to complete
>   before it is recognized on the internet.

it means **New Host(A or AAAA)** needs time to Propagation.is it correct? if yes why do my settings affect instantly ?

I need a clear answer around this question topic . all others tell i must have CNAME but my settings solve my problem. what's wrong here?

i am using **Windows Server 2016**

Comment: Your settings are correct and your provider's instructions are wrong (at least for what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: Can you share the domain name?

Comment: @DusanBajic can you clarify it? i mean complete description .

Comment: @user3788685 why do you need?

Comment: @Mr.AF because you wanted to know if something had updated, propagated or changed and if your config was built correct and valid. If not it's not a problem.

Comment: @user3788685 currently Domain name servers and domain name replay ping request with my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That propagation article is misleading: when clients resolve hostname to ip address, they cache the resolved value for some time (TTL, and that value you set when you create a DNS record), so they don't have to resolve it for each subsequent request.

So, when you **change** DNS record value, clients will not be immediately aware of it because they are using the cached value, until TTL expires.

When you create a new record, there is nothing cached on client side so there is nothing to wait for!

About DNS records, it is difficult to say why your provider's instructions mention `ns1` hostname, that you will need to check with them.

About `A` and `CNAME` (in somewhat layman's terms):

Clients (your site visitors' devices) need to know the ip address for a hostname they are trying to access. That is the purpose of `A` record: when you create `www A x.y.z.w` that tells your client that `x.y.z.w` is the ip address of `www.example.com`. Nothing more, nothing less, but it is necessary!

`CNAME` is just alias (another hostname) for the hostname that you already defined in `A` record. So, `website CNAME www.example.com` means that `website.example.com` has the same IP address as www.example.com. When you, sometime in the future, change the ip address of `www.example.com`, there will be no need to update `website`, it will also immediately point to new ip address, because it is just alias of `www.example.com`. 
Technically you could also create an `A` record for `website`, with address `x.y.z.w` and it would have the same effect, except that if you ever need to update ip address in the future, you will need to update two `A` records.

Comment: it's not about client side domain resolving it's all about server side configuration.mainly CNAME and A Record and what i have done in server side.moreover, propagation is a clue for my question but not a main problem.

Comment: You asked "it means New Host(A or AAAA) needs time to Propagation.is it correct? if yes why do my settings affect instantly ? I need a clear answer around this topic ?", I am not really sure what else is confusing you? If it is about purpose of `A` or `CNAME` records, I could only copy/paste what you can easily google, unless you have some specific question to clarify?

Comment: These are problems.why provider guide lines do not works for me? and what is difference between my settings and provider guide lines.what's CNAME when to use what's A Record when to use.i had read a lot of websites around.but i need deep details .